# Rails 3: Sorting Select dropdown in View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code in my view that produces a dropdown list and I was wondering if there was a quick and easy way just in the view to sort this list alphabetically?

```
 <% @customer.customer_apps.where("CA_enabled = 1").each do |a| %>
      <li><%= link_to a.app_name_condensed(40), app_path(a) + path_suffix, :class => 'app-link' %></li>
  <% end %>
```

Here's an image of the dropdown:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read the [ordering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) section of Rails guides

```
<% @customer.customer_apps.where("CA_enabled = 1").order(:name).each do |a| %>
  <li><%= link_to a.app_name_condensed(40), app_path(a) + path_suffix, :class => 'app-link' %></li>
<% end %>
```

Replace `name` by the field you want to sort

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ben! Appreciate it. Even added .order('created_at DESC') to get the job done. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it was useful. Cheers ;)